# Screen size problem with Ubuntu 14.04 x86_64 in virtualbox

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 from Windows, using virtualbox 5.0. I tried several options to make size of Ubuntu in virtual box larger, but none helped so far.

- I am using latest virtual box with latest guest add on installed.
- `sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-dkms virtualbox-guest-utils virtualbox-guest-x11`
- I went to Ubuntu 'software and Updates' and made sure that under 'Additional Drivers' tab, 'using x86 visualization solution...' is active.
- In virtualbox window, under view->virtual screen 1, all 'resize to' options are disabled.

None of these options helped. This is frustrating. Any comments or help? Can the problem be I am using 64 bit system? Does this problem occurs in earlier/later versions? If not, please suggest a 'good' version of Ubuntu for virtualbox.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is caused by a lack of video memory. By default, Virtualbox only allocates 12MB to an Ubuntu VM, and as such, the size of the virtual machine is small:

[image]

The way to fix this is fairly straightforward.

Once you create the VM and install Ubuntu, restart. Once you do that, go ahead and press the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>. Make sure to press the **right** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, not the left.

Alternatively, you can go up to the top of the VM window and click *Devices* > *Insert Guest Additions CD Image*:

[image]

A window may pop up saying `"VBOXADDITIONS_VERSIONUMBERS" contains software intended to be automatically started. Would you like to run it?`. You can click yes, this will just skip the next two steps.

If the window I just mentioned *doesn't* automatically pop up, go ahead and click on the CD icon in the Unity taskbar:

[image]

Go ahead and close the Nautilus window that opens up, and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.

This will open a Terminal window, in which you should enter `cd /media/YOURUSERNAME/VBOXADDITIONS` and then hit <kbd>Tab</kbd>, then <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

[image]

Then, go ahead and type `sudo chmod +x VboxLinuxAdditions.run && sudo ./VboxLinuxAdditions.run`.

You may be prompted for your password, go ahead and put it in.

Once you do so, the installer will run. Once it completes:

[image]

you'll need to restart. Close the Terminal window and restart the VM, and you're almost done!

Once the VM shuts down, right-click on the VM in the main VirtualBox window and select the `Settings` item:

[image]

Once the window opens, go ahead and select the **Display** tab along the left.

Then, drag the *Video Memory* option all the way to the right. What previously said `12 MB` should now say `128 MB`.

[image]

Go ahead and start up the VM, and you should be able to go full screen, as well as any other size you want!

Comment: Thanks a ton for this answer! Worked successfully! I saw many other blogs, posts, webpages, and tried many different things. But this method worked. Thanks again! By the way, in your last picture, virtualbox Ubuntu settings -> display -> video -> 'Extended Features' -> Enable 2D, 3D acceleration. What these options are? Are they connected with graphics performance?

Comment: @343_458 Glad I was able to help! As for the options, they simply allow VirtualBox to have direct access to the GPU's 3D and 2D rendering capabilities, instead of via software. It's a personal choice, I've never noticed any difference in performance/load on your physical system with it on or off. Granted, I've never done anything super *insane* with a VM, I've just used them to test various things. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!

Comment: I've found [some apps](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/6203) fail  with 3D enabled.